# Abnormal $PATH on OS X

Tags: python, macos, bash, path

I realize that this is probably a simple question but, I'm 95% my path is screwed up. The result of opening a new terminal and typing [echo $PATH] is:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/bmoog/.rvm/bin
```

Looking around it seems that it should be something more like:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Any guesses as to why I am going into my Python.framework?

Comment: where did you get the 2.7 installer you used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python installers from python.org, and from many other sources, do not install anything into /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin. Instead, they install everything into a `bin` directory within the framework, and then give you an option to add that `bin` directory to your path. (Generally, any script that get installed either with that Python, or with packages you later install into it, also end up in the framework's `bin` directory.)

So, at some point, you ran a third-party Python 2.7 installer, and checked the checkbox/manually ran the post-install script/etc. to do this.

All the option does is prepend the following 4 lines to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

(Possibly with the typo `orginal` for `original` fixed, depending on your version.)

So, you can revert by just `cp ~/.bash_profile.pysave ~/.bash_profile` if you're not afraid of losing any subsequent changes… or, more safely, just edit the file in your favorite text editor and remove those lines.

---

Of course if you do this, you will no longer be able to run that third-party Python, or its `2to3`, or an `ipython` you installed for it, etc., without specifying a horrible absolute path…

---

Meanwhile, you probably didn't need a third-party Python 2.7 in the first place. Apple has been providing Python 2.7 for at least three major OS versions now (2.7.5 in Mavericks, 2.7.2 in Lion and Mountain Lion), as `/usr/bin/python`. If you don't want this 2.7 on your PATH, you probably don't want it at all, so I'd just uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `~/.bash_profile` and then all the files it includes to see where the extra path is coming from. Somewhere there will be a line like:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}
```

But do you really care?